# In Java, how can I use a variable initialized inside a try/catch block elsewhere in the program?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, try-catch, variable-initialization

I have a basic quadratic formula program, but I've modified the beginning to end the program if any value other than a double is entered. However, because I've done this, I can't seem to be able to use the value inputted anywhere else in the program. Here are the first few lines:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuadraticFormula
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double a, b, c; 
    Scanner reads = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("General equation: \"ax^2 + bx + c\"");
    System.out.print("Enter value of \"a\": ");

    try { 
      String doubleString = reads.nextLine();
      a = Double.parseDouble(doubleString); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid Data Type. Please enter a number");
    }
```

The rest of the program asks for the values of b and c, and then carries out the quadratic equation, retuning the roots of whatever equation was entered. However, because the value of a is defined inside the try section, the compiler tells me that a hasn't been initialized. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I do want to use the data inputted by the user in the program (stored as doubleString)––but a number. My immediate problem is the compiler error, but is there any way to use the information inputted even though it's inside the try block? Because when I tried to equate double a to double doubleString outside the block it said doubleString didn't exist.

Comment: Give `a` a default initial value; consider if there is an exception. Without a default value, `a` has no value at all.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't think that's what the OP's asking. It's the input of the scanner that can't be used anywhere. @Caroline `String doubleString = reads.nextLine();` wouldn't throw an exception and hence doesn't have to be inside the try block. It's the parsing that might throw the exception.

Comment: @RahulSharma *However, because the value of a is defined inside the try section, the compiler tells me that a hasn't been initialized. How do I fix this?*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch whoops. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Elliot Frisch said, you can just initialize a to a value (0) and take care that you don't get any wrong values due to failed parsing.
In your case this would probably mean to return/exit the program with the error message.

This is actually a common pattern.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuadraticFormula
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
double a = 0, b, c; 
Scanner reads = new Scanner(System.in); 

System.out.println("General equation: \"ax^2 + bx + c\"");
System.out.print("Enter value of \"a\": ");

try { 
  String doubleString = reads.nextLine();
  a = Double.parseDouble(doubleString); 
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid Data Type. Please enter a number");
  return;
}
//do work with a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize a when you declare it :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  double a = 0.0;
  double b, c; 
  Scanner reads = new Scanner(System.in);
```

The other thing you can do is declare a as a "Class Property" :

```
public class QuadraticFormula
{
    protected static double a = 0.0; 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double b, c; 
        Scanner reads = new Scanner(System.in); 
        try { 
            String doubleString = reads.nextLine();
            QuadraticFormula.a = Double.parseDouble(doubleString); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Data Type. Please enter a number");
        }
```

Please note how the Class property (a) MUST be accessed using a static reference within main() as main() is static, which breaks the Java rule of using getter/setter to access Class properties.  One thing I would recommend you should begin to learn how to package Class functionality outside of main()...outside of static references...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuadraticFormula {

    protected  double a = 0.0;

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        QuadraticFormula lnewItem = new QuadraticFormula();
        try {
            lnewItem.doSomething();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public  void    doSomething () throws Exception {
        double b, c; 
        Scanner reads = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("General equation: \"ax^2 + bx + c\"");
        System.out.print("Enter value of \"a\": ");

        try { 
          String doubleString = reads.nextLine();
          setA ( Double.parseDouble(doubleString) ); 
          System.out.println("setA() - [" + getA() + "]");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Invalid Data Type. Please enter a number");
        }

    }

    public double getA () {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA ( double a ) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Please note in the last section of code, all the static references are removed other than main().  New getter/setter methods are in place for the Class property a, thus enforcing Java's data encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fixes for this, one is to simply return from your main method when an exception is throw like so:

```
    double a;
    Scanner reads = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("General equation: \"ax^2 + bx + c\"");
    System.out.print("Enter value of \"a\": ");

    try {
        String doubleString = reads.nextLine();
        a = Double.parseDouble(doubleString);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Data Type. Please enter a number");
        return;
    }
```

The other option stated by others is giving 'a' an initial value. I would suggest initializing it as NaN (Not a Number) and then checking it has been properly initialized before using it like so:

```
    double a = Double.NaN;
    Scanner reads = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("General equation: \"ax^2 + bx + c\"");
    System.out.print("Enter value of \"a\": ");

    try {
        String doubleString = reads.nextLine();
        a = Double.parseDouble(doubleString);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Data Type. Please enter a number");
    }

    if(Double.isNaN(a)){
        System.out.println("Variable 'a' is invalid, please enter a valid number.");
    }
    else {
        double result = 2 * a;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of this line:

```
double a, b, c;
```

just replace it with this:

```
double a=0, b, c;
```